# Mongo C++ driver crashes with bad allocation

Tags: c++, mongodb, driver

I compiled c++ driver from https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/tree/26compat (used 26compat branch for compiling the driver using the command scons --64 --sharedclient --dynamic-windows --release --full --prefix=C:/mongo-cxx-driver-legacy/mongo-client-release_64 --use-system-boost --cpppath=C:/local/boost_1_55_0_64 --libpath=C:/local/boost_1_55_0_64/lib64-msvc-12.0 install-mongoclient )
NOTE: installed all the pre requisites like- boost packages etc as mentioned in the https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/wiki/Download%20and%20Compile

I wrote a sample program (attached) where I am just getting the mongo connection , with the connection wanted to find the count of documents for a BSON object.
here is the program-

```
#if defined(_WIN32)
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#endif
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define STATIC_LIBMONGOCLIENT
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <mongo/client/dbclient.h> // for the driver
#include <mongo/client/dbclientinterface.h> // for the driver
#include <mongo/bson/bson.h>

#pragma   comment(lib,"libmongoclient.lib")
using namespace mongo;

int main(){

    DBClientConnection mongoclient;

    string errmsg;
    try {

        if (!mongoclient.connect("16.166.233.124:27017", errmsg)) {
            cout << "couldn't connect : " << errmsg << endl; 
        }
        cout << "\nSuresh-Test264  After getting the connection....\n" << endl;;
        const char * ns = "suresh.test";
        BSONObj res = BSONObjBuilder().append("age", 33).obj();
        int limit, skip, options;
        limit = skip = options = 0;
        unsigned long long count = 0;
        count = mongoclient.count(ns, res);
        cout << "count of existing documents in collection test.foo : " << count << endl;
        }
    catch (exception &e) {
        std::cout << "caught " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }


}
```

I was successful in getting the connection, however count operation is throwing a bad memory allocation exception. [this exception is thrown for most of the functions defined in DBClientConnection]

The thread 0x33c0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFD79940D in ConsoleApplication2.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x00000000001DF6F0.
First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFD79940D in ConsoleApplication2.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x00000000001DD200.
First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFD79940D in ConsoleApplication2.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x0000000000000000.
First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFD79940D in ConsoleApplication2.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x00000000001DD200.
The program '[11696] ConsoleApplication2.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

debug error messages-

> ConsoleApplication2.exe!_heap_alloc_dbg_impl(unsigned __int64 nSize, int nBlockUse, const char * szFileName, int nLine, int * errno_tmp) Line 396   C++
>       ConsoleApplication2.exe!_nh_malloc_dbg_impl(unsigned __int64 nSize, int nhFlag, int nBlockUse, const char * szFileName, int nLine, int * errno_tmp) Line 239    C++
>       ConsoleApplication2.exe!_nh_malloc_dbg(unsigned __int64 nSize, int nhFlag, int nBlockUse, const char * szFileName, int nLine) Line 302  C++
>       ConsoleApplication2.exe!malloc(unsigned __int64 nSize) Line 56  C++
>       ConsoleApplication2.exe!operator new(unsigned __int64 size) Line 59 C++
>       ConsoleApplication2.exe!std::_Allocate(unsigned __int64 _Count, std::_Container_proxy * __formal) Line 28    C++
>       ConsoleApplication2.exe!std::allocator::allocate(unsigned __int64 _Count) Line 579   C++
>       ConsoleApplication2.exe!std::_String_alloc<0,std::_String_base_types > >::_Alloc_proxy() Line 666 C++
>       ConsoleApplication2.exe!std::_String_alloc<0,std::_String_base_types > >::_String_alloc<0,std::_String_base_types > >(const std::allocator & __formal) Line 645   C++
>       ConsoleApplication2.exe!std::basic_string,std::allocator >::basic_string,std::allocator >(const char * _Ptr) Line 780   C++
>       ConsoleApplication2.exe!main() Line 33  C++
>       [External Code]

My environment includes-
Windows 7, 64 bit.
Visual studio 2013
mongodb 2.4.4

Answer (score 0):

I answered your equivalent question on the mongodb-user mailing list as follows:

I ran your program against the 26compat branch on linux using address sanitizer, and everything looked fine. So I have a few questions:

- You are building with --sharedclient, however your #pragma names the static version of the library. Did you intend to link the static or dynamic version of mongoclient?
- You are building with --dynamic-windows, which will cause the mongo client library to select the dynamic windows runtime library. Are you also compiling your application against the dynamic windows runtime libraries? The selected runtime library must match between the mongo client library and the application.